# DirectFB on raspberry pi - vertical line color problem

Tags: pi-3

I write and run a simple DirectFB program & draw multiple lines via `DrawLine`. I have problem with the color of vertical lines. I choose an specific color with the `SetColor` but vertical lines have the other color. The other lines have correct colors corresponding to the `SetColor`.

It is my code, which the main part borrowed from http://www.directfb.net/docs/DirectFB_Tutorials/simple.html:

```
#define DFBCHECK(x...)                                         \
{                                                            \
DFBResult err = x;                                         \
                                                           \
if (err != DFB_OK)                                         \
  {                                                        \
    fprintf( stderr, "%s <%d>:\n\t", __FILE__, __LINE__ ); \
    DirectFBErrorFatal( #x, err );                         \
  }                                                        \
}
```

...

```
    IDirectFB *dfb=NULL;
    IDirectFBSurface *primary=NULL;
    DFBSurfaceDescription dsc;
    DFBRegion rect;

    DFBCHECK(DirectFBInit(&argc, &argv));
    DFBCHECK(DirectFBCreate(&dfb));
    DFBCHECK(dfb->SetCooperativeLevel(dfb, DFSCL_FULLSCREEN));
    dsc.flags=DSDESC_CAPS;
    dsc.caps =DSCAPS_PRIMARY|DSCAPS_FLIPPING;
    DFBCHECK(dfb->CreateSurface(dfb, &dsc, primary));

    DFBCHECK(primary->SetColor(primary, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff));
    DFBCHECK(primary->FillRectangle(primary, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    DFBCHECK(primary->Flip(primary, NULL, 0));

    DFBCHECK(primary->SetColor(primary, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff));
    DFBCHECK(primary->DrawLine (primary, 10, 10, 900, 10));
    DFBCHECK(primary->DrawLine (primary, 200, 200, 900, 200));
    DFBCHECK(primary->DrawLine (primary, 10, 10, 10, 200));
    DFBCHECK(primary->DrawLine (primary, 100, 10, 100, 200));
    DFBCHECK(primary->DrawLine (primary, 10, 10, 100, 200));
    DFBCHECK(primary->DrawLine (primary, 10, 10, 900, 300));
    DFBCHECK(primary->DrawLine (primary, 150, 10, 150, 200));

    DFBCHECK(primary->Flip(primary, NULL, 0));

    primary->Release( primary );
    dfb->Release( dfb );
```

Comment: Could you post your program or the part where it draws the lines?

Comment: I add my codes.

Answer (score 1):

It was the initialization issue.
Add these lines to */root/.directfbrc*. The last line was the key.

```
fbdev=/dev/fb1
mode=480x320
depth=16
pixelformat=RGB16
```